# Show that $b^{p-1} = [1]$ using Lagrange

Tags: abstract-algebra

I Would be very happy with help to solving this:

*Let p be a prime and let b be an element in $\mathbb{Z}^{\times}_p$. Show that $b^{p-1} = [1]$*

---

The first thing I have thought about using is: If p is a prime then a random group G of order p is cyclic and isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_p$

Then I thought I might have to use Lagrange's theorem: If G is a group of finite order and $K \leq G$
is a subgroup, then $|G|=[G:K]|K|$. And $|K|$ vil divide |G|

Am I on the right track? I feel like I need to connect these things. And understand the problem better.

With regards to $\mathbb{Z}^{\times}_p $, how do I interpret the $\times$ as the power of $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: If $G$ is any finite group then for any $a\in G$ we have $a^{|G|}=e$ where $e$ is the identity element. This simply follows from the fact that the order of every element divides $|G|$. (which follows from Lagrange's theorem). Your problem is just a special case, because $|\mathbb{Z^{\times}_p}|=p-1$.

Comment: Thank you! Du you know by chance also what the $\times$ sign mean in $\mathbb{Z}^{\times}_p $?

Comment: If $R$ is any ring with identity then $R^{\times}$ is the set of all invertible elements. It is a group with respect to multiplication. For example, if $F$ is a field then $F^{\times}=F\setminus\{0\}$, because all nonzero elements in a field have a multiplicative inverse. So $\mathbb{Z^{\times}_p}$ is the group of the elements which have a multiplicative inverse mod $p$. The operation here is multiplication mod $p$. (not to get confused with the additive group $\mathbb{Z_p}$)

Comment: Thank you for that nice explanation!